# Modifying the default value for a multiple variable from the command-line with Scons?

Tags: scons

How do I modify the defaults from the command-line for this multiple option variable:

```
options = Variables()

options.Add(
    "FLAGS",
    "Compiler Flags.",
    ["-Wall", "-Werror", "-O2"]
)
```

This fails to do the right thing:

> scons FLAGS=-Wall,-Werror

This is scons 1.1.0 and tcsh.

Comment: That's an old version of SCons, any chance of upgrading to a newer version?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure in which version of SCons these functions were introduced, and it may be possible they arent available in your version, but you can use the ParseFlags() and MergeFlags() to *automatically* put command line options into their Construction Variables, as mentioned [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c1818.html).